# VIM Function Parameter Passing

Tags: vim

I am trying to create a simple vim script function and I am having trouble. This function needs to take two input strings and run the search and replace all instances of them. I have the following right now:

```
  function! FindAndReplaceAll(from, to)                                           
     echo a:from                                                                   
     :%s/a:from/a:to/gc                                                            
  endfunction
```

When I do:

```
:call FindAndReplaceAll("test", "test2")
```

The echo a:from works correctly but the :%s... is acting on the from and to literals instead. I noticed my vim syntax high lighting isn't even highlighting those as variables so I seem to have a basic syntax problem.

My questions are:

1. What is the correct syntax with this? I would appreciate an explanation of why rather than just the answer. Why is the above incorrect?
2. Anyway to allow for this to be called as

   :call FindAndReplaceAll(test, test2)

So I don't have to add quotes...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need change

`:%s/a:from/a:to/gc`

to:

`exe '%s/' . a:from . '/' . a:to . '/gc'`

Your statement is interpreted *literally*. i.e. it will replace string "a:from" with string "a:to" in the current buffer.

But what you intend is to replace string evaluated by `a:from` with string evaluated by `a:to`. That can be achieved by built-in `exe[cute]` function(you can get help by typing: `:h exe` in command-line mode).

As for your second question, you have to use quotes otherwise they will be taken as variables.

Answer (score 2):

The command line should be called with `execute', instead of direct text:

```
 function! FindAndReplaceAll(from, to)                                           
     echo    a:from                                                                   
     execute "%s/" . a:from . "/" . a:to . "/gc"                                                            
 endfunction
```